# No content in share dialog when calling presentShareDialogWithParams:clientState:handler

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, ios7, share

I have followed Facebook's guide, found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share), for sharing a link from within an iOS app, but when the share dialog opens in the facebook app, there is no link, or preview, or pictures. This is all I see:

[image]

If I enter a comment there, I can post it, but only the comment is visible in the post, not the content I am commenting on. Above my comment it says "2 hours ago via ..." and the name of my app.

I have of course created a facbook app, and it is "live" (not in developement mode). I hva also called `[FBSettings setDefaultAppID:];` and `[FBAppEvents activateApp];` in `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

This is my code:

```
NSString *name = @"Name here";
NSString *url = @"https://google.com/";
NSString *url = @"Caption here";
NSString *linkDescription = @"Description here";
NSString *imageUrl = @"http://i.imgur.com/zLS0g9Z.jpg";

//*

// Check if the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
FBLinkShareParams *params = [[FBLinkShareParams alloc] init];
params.link = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
params.name = name;
params.caption = caption;
params.linkDescription = linkDescription;
params.picture = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl];

// If the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:params]) {
    // Present the share dialog
    [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithParams:params clientState:nil handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
        if(error) {
            // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
            // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
            NSLog(@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description);
        } else {
            // Success
            //NSLog(@"result %@", results);
        }
    }];

} else {
    // Fallback: Present the feed dialog
}
```

The same thing also happens when i try to share an Open Graph story ([here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/open-graph/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. My url contained some special characters (I replaced the actual url in my code with https://google.com/ before posting the code here). Simply adding the line:

```
url = [url stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

resolved my issue :)